# How to less complicated this request

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this request

```
select COALESCE (SUBSTR(description, 0, INSTR(description, '#')-1),description) FROM dual
```

Test:

When : description = `123456789 # 11` => Result = `123456789`

When : description = `123456789`      => Result = `123456789`

Is there any idea how to less complicated , because like you see it's so hard to read

Comment: Please tag your question with the database being used.

Comment: ok i will do that thanks

Comment: You mean make it less complicated for you. Optimization does not come into it.

Comment: yeah thats't what i want

Comment: Is # Sign common or any other character could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all characters after `#` use the regexp_replace in the first line;
note, that the trailing blank is preserved.

```
 regexp_replace(description, '([^#]*).*', '\1')
```

The second line `D2` removes anything after the first `#` or *blank*

```
 regexp_replace(description, '([^ #]*).*', '\1')
```

Here the  sample query - the quotes show  only the presence of blanks:

```
select  
description,
'"'||regexp_replace(description, '([^#]*).*', '\1')||'"' d1,
'"'||regexp_replace(description, '([^ #]*).*', '\1')||'"' d2 
FROM 
(select '123456789 # 11' description from dual union all
 select '123456789' description from dual);
```

result

```
DESCRIPTION    D1             D2           
-------------- -------------- --------------
123456789 # 11 "123456789 "   "123456789"    
123456789      "123456789"    "123456789"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(description, '^[^ #]*[ ]')
```

I doubt this would be any faster.

Comment: ... but them again that might be a bit complicated

Comment: Not work, result of  select regexp_substr('123456 # ZE', '^[^ #]') from dual was 1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job too:

```
select CASE 
         when INSTR(description, '#') > 0 then
                substr(description,0,INSTR(description, '#')-1)
         else description
       END new_description
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get numerical part from description field

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('12345678 # 11','[[:alpha:]]') from dual`